# Auth Header in Vaadin 7

Tags: javascript, tomcat, vaadin

Hey guys maybe you can help me. 
I have multiple tomcat servers on which different vaadin apps are running. 
I want a basic authentication across all tomcat servers and apps.
 So I want to login and send everytime I open another app the auth header.
 Is there a way to achieve that?
 I tried with javascript, but I cant manipulate the url with my created XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: When implementing single sign on you need to take in account single origin policy and so many other things that I recommend taking a look to technologies like Keyclock. One way to get started is to look for example apps like this https://github.com/chvndb/keycloak-spring-vaadin-demo

Comment: Well, Keycloak sounds interessingt, but there are way too less tomcat vaadin 7 examples. I havent found one. The openid-connect works fine, but I am clueless how to do the saml.